# How display a loading image correctly on Android phone

Tags: android, loading, gif, animated-gif, loading-image

I have been trying to use a .gif file from my resources, but I get no movement when it loads.  I am using it as a loading image while I am doing an asynchronous task.  I was previously using a progress dialog but now I would like to display the image myself and not use a dialog.    How can I get this image to display correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using AnimationDrawable:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Basically, you should split each of the frames in your gif into separate files - such as .png file (say if it had transparency) and specify these files in the `<animation-list>` instead. You can also control the duration of each frame.

See the link for code example

Comment: do you happen to know if there are any default android loading images that are usable instead?

Comment: Im not sure if android has them, but if you have an image editor, you can copy and rotate the ones off a google search:http://www.google.ca/images?hl=en&q=loading+animation&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1280&bih=918

Answer (score 0):

If you are deadset on using a gif image you can just use a WebView instead of an ImageView. Then make an html doc that displays your gif image. When you show it in the WebView it will be animated for you.